# How to prevent PO Box in address field?

Tags: html, regex

I use HTML5 patter to validate address field input. Here is example of my code:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="address1" id="address1" value="" maxlength="40" required>
```

I would like to use pattern attribute to prevent PO box in the address field. Can anyone help me achieve that with patter regex?

Comment: Use a negative lookahead that matches all the forms of `PO Box` that you want to prohibit.

Comment: @Barmar Can you please provide any example?

Comment: You'll have to provide more details. Addresses can vary _**widely**_ so you'll have to exactly define what you want to exclude. I've seen all the following variations (and I'm sure there are more) how a person has written a PO Box ... `PO Box 123`, `P.O. Box 123`, `P.O. Box #123`, `Box 123`, `POB 123` etc. upper/lowercase, spacing, with/without the `#` and so on.

Comment: @StephenP Any combination of PO box should be prevented. In the existing program they use this: `var reNewTest=/[Bb][Oo][Xx][\d]/ if(reNewTest.test(Addr1))` I'm not sure how loose is that regex.

Comment: Something like `.*(?![Bb][Oo][Xx]\s+\d)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pattern with a negative lookahead. See [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) and replace the word in those patterns with the pattern that matches `box` followed by a number.

```
.*(?![Bb][Oo][Xx]\s+\d)
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="((?![Bb][Oo][Xx]\s+\d).)*">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```